# Difference in performance between JpaRepository and ElasticSearchRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am learning the Spring-Data-Elasticsearch. For searching the entities in my application, I call the `search()` method of `ElasticSearchRepository`.

I also have the `JpaRepository` implementation for basic CRUD operations.

I can see that we can define specific `findByXXX` method in `ElasticSearchRepository` as well.

For such `findByFieldName` which repository should I use, `ElasticSearchRepository` or `JpaRepository`, basically what would be the performance difference between the two, in this case.

For search obviously, the **`ElasticSearchRepository` is a performance efficient option.**

Also, this question came to mind because I have generated the project using jHipster, and it is using `ElasticSearchRepository` for search and `JpaRepository` for other findBy and create, update, delete operations.